# Migrated portal from SharePoint 2007 to 2010 can't change layout

Tags: 2010, 2007, migration, page-layout

After migrating a portal from SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint 2010 the "Page Layout" option is disabled
And after trying different approaches it gets enabled but it's always empty (Drop down doesn't appear)

Any Help ?

Comment: Is the Publishing feature activated on the site?

Comment: Yes "SharePoint Server Publishing" Feature is active

Comment: Is the page a Publishing page?  A generally easy way to tell is if it is located in the Pages library.  This is not foolproof but is a good indicator.

Comment: Yes, it's in the pages library :(

Comment: This means that SharePoint thinks that it is not a publishing page for some reason.  If you create a new view of your Pages library and include the 'Content Type' and 'Page Layout' fields, what values appear there for this particular page?

Comment: What do you mean with a new view ? you mean a new page ?

Comment: Also please note that when I opened the site settings page I was able to assign a default layout for this subsite and it worked fine, but I can't change it from the ribbon

Comment: Go to your Pages library and create a new view.  The Pages Library can be found viewing the problem page, then selecting 'Page' - 'View All Pages' from the ribbon.  This will take you a standard list view of the pages library. from there you can create a new view or even just temporarily add those columns to the default view.

Comment: Okay, I can create a new view and page layout column was already checked but the content type column wasn't checked

Comment: What content type and page layout is listed for the page you are having trouble with?

Comment: Actually I found something weird, when I click on the arrow next to any page I get a message which tells me that the page has been deleted or not found

Comment: And also the view properties control in the ribbon is disabled